# HTML5 Canvas: Draw matrix with fixed first row and first column

Tags: javascript, matrix, scroll, visualization, html5-canvas

I am using HTML5 canvas in my application to render a large matrix (1000*1000) of cells that are either filled or not.

However I fail to keep the first column and the first row fixed while allow for scrolling the rest of the matrix. Here's a picture of what I'd like to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/24kIV.png

The scrolling could either be the CSS/browser scrollbar or a javascript_based scrolling.

Any hints on how to keep the first row and column fixed?

**Update:**
When scrolling to the left/right the first row should scroll too, same for up/down scrolling and the first column.

Comment: What about three canvases (left, top and main), and put the main in a scrollable element?

Comment: I thought of that, however the difficulty is to scroll the first row too when scrolling right/left and to scroll the first column when scrolling up/down too. To this I haven't found a solution yet

Answer (score 2):

You could make a layout with three `div`s, each one containing a canvas, and scroll the fixed element when the main element is scrolled: http://jsfiddle.net/SjBE5/.

```
document.getElementById("maindiv").onscroll = ​​​​function() {
    document.getElementById("topdiv").scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
    document.getElementById("leftdiv").scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
};​
```

Comment: @Dobbylan: That's great. Just wanted to note that this may not be the most performant solution, though. I do think it's the most straight-forward one.